# Pyinstaller raises error: system cannot access the file

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I'm having some trouble using pyinstaller to generate executables. After using the command pyinstaller --onefile "filename.py", an error is raised, mentioning that the system cannot access the file, as follows:
[image]

As anyone dealt with such problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller reads a Python script written by you. For the majority of programs, this can be done by:  `pyinstaller yourscript.py`
But if it doesn't work for you, try using this:  `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed yourscript.py`